# Unicorn on a Stick — what does it do?

Tags: terraria

I killed a unicorn and it dropped the item called "Unicorn on a Stick", which is the decapitated unicorn's head with a stick jammed in it. It is not a crafting material and cannot be equipped. What does it do?

Comment: [Unicorn Mount](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I2SAblOluME), you mean?

Comment: @Jamal the name of the item is Unicorn on a Stick. It does look like the picture. Video's just some dude ranting about a pre-release screenshot.

Comment: Have you tried placing it as a piece of furniture? I suspect that's all it is.

Comment: Ah.  I haven't heard of it, then.  Nothing about it on a wiki, either.

Comment: @SaintWacko no, it is not placeable. Equipping it via a hotkey doesn't seem to do anything other make the character "ride" it.

Comment: <strike>PETA target self-identification tool</strike> bragging rights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [unicorn on a stick](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Stick_Unicorn) is an item gained from killing unicorns. It is a green rarity item and can be sold for a some money (1 sliver).  Not much is known about it except that it is just a loot item. It can't be equipped/eaten or placed. However when you hold it it appears that you ride it.

[image: stick unicorn (taken from Terraria wiki)]

Comment: That's what I first found, but wasn't sure about it since there's little information.  Hopefully these new wiki entries will get updated.

Comment: No, that is actually not what the item is called, I can see its name when I mouse over it and it is "Unicorn on a Stick". Its sale price is a whopping 1 silver.

Comment: While there is nothing inherently wrong with googling answers, this is one of the pitfalls you can fall into by doing so.  That wiki page is little more than a template. What you've got here basically amounts to "I don't know".

Comment: The wiki got the name wrong (maybe from information before release). The page is still for the item as all the information match the item and there is no item called "stick unicorn" in the game.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the unicorn on a stick has no use except that when you hold it, you appear to be riding it. (and it can be sold for a lot of money, but as we probably all agree, riding round on a fake unicorn is more fun.

Comment: A lot of money, you say?

Comment: As far as I know. I haven't tried it.

Comment: @kotekzot Have you seen my answer?